# Using a command-line utility to perform the following map-updates

Tags: shell, command-line, awk, terminal

I'm a complete newbie to using command-line utilities and am wondering how to process information as following:

`mapping.txt`:

```
80  001 002
81  011 012 013 014
82  021 022
...
```

`input.txt`:

```
81  103823044
80  103823054
81  103823064
...
```

Desired `output.txt`:

```
103823044|011|
103823044|012|
103823044|013|
103823044|014|
103823054|001|
103823054|002|
103823064|011|
103823064|012|
103823064|013|
103823064|014|
```

I've done simple mapping wherein the column numbers are fixed but I'm unsure of how to map a dynamic number of columns to the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If order is not important, join and awk can do the job easily.

```
$ join <(sort input.txt) <(sort mapping.txt) | awk -v OFS="|" '{for (i=3;i<NF;i++) print $2, $i OFS}'
103823054|001|
103823044|011|
103823044|012|
103823044|013|
103823064|011|
103823064|012|
103823064|013|
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a GNU awk script that uses multi-dimensional arrays to do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { OFS="|" }

FNR==NR { for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) a[$1][$i]; next }

$1 in a { for(k in a[$1]) print $2, k, "" }
```

If you save that to a file like `script.awk` and then `chmod +x script.awk` you can run it like:

```
$ ./script.awk mapping.txt input.txt
103823044|011|
103823044|012|
103823044|013|
103823044|014|
103823054|002|
103823054|001|
103823064|011|
103823064|012|
103823064|013|
103823064|014|
```

Here's a breakdown of the script:

- `BEGIN` - set the output field separator to `|`
- `FNR==NR` - process the first file (`mapping.txt`) and store the data in a multi-dimensional array by `$1` first, then by the other fields.  `next` to skip any other line processing.
- `$1 in a` - test to see if the line has a mapping.  If so, print the corresponding mappings out in order(also GNU awk).  The commas in the `print` command are converted to the `OFS` value.

It could be remade a "one-liner" like:

```
awk -v OFS="|" 'FNR==NR {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) a[$1][$i]; next} $1 in a {for(k in a[$1]) print $2, k, ""}' mapping.txt input.txt
```

Here's a version of the script that uses a single dimensional array to store `$0` then `split()`s it later to preserve order:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { OFS="|" }

FNR==NR { a[$1]=$0; next }

$1 in a { c=split(a[$1], b); for(i=2;i<=c;i++) print $2, b[i], "" }
```

Comment: I get the following error: `$ awk -v OFS="|" 'FNR==NR {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) a[$1][$i]; next} $1 in a {for(k in a[$1]) print $2, k, ""}' mapping.txt input.txt > 3.txt
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 FNR==NR {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) >>>  a[$1][ <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1`

Comment: I suspect you're not using an awk that understands multi-dimensional arrays.  What version of awk are you using?

Comment: I added a version that's mac awk friendly.